# PHP cannot pull data from from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull data from mysql table using php, here is my code. This code resides within html body.

```
<?php
    // Connects to your Database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "Hxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("core_config") or die(mysql_error());

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vrf group by vrf") or die(mysql_error());

    Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";

        while ( $info = mysql_fetch_array ( $data )) {
            Print "<tr>";
            Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['Switch'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['vlan'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['ip_address'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['vrf'] . " </td></tr>";
        }

    Print "</table>";
?>
```

For some reason when I execute the html in a browser I dont get the desired result. I get following output.

```
"; while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { Print ""; Print "Name: ".$info['Switch'] . " "; Print "Name: ".$info['vlan'] . " "; Print "Name: ".$info['ip_address'] . " "; Print 
"Pet: ".$info['vrf'] . " "; } Print ""; ?>
```

I have done extensive research and I cannot seem get this to work, please help.

Comment: Try removing `Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";` and replacing it with an echo?

Comment: which is table and which is fields because there is vrf as table and as field name in group by..? so vrf is also field name of vrf table.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your file as `.php` not as `.html`

Comment: add this as comment not as answer..please

Comment: Well, in fact, this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a case sensitive either change your Change Print to echo or change Print to print

```
print "abccdd";
```

or

```
echo "abc";
```

Save the file with extension .php and not .html

another error found in your code is

```
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
```

change it to

```
   print "<table border='cellpadding=3;'>";
```

Comment: there is not issue with case sensitive.

Comment: Variables and constants are case sensitive; functions and language constructs are not.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with `echo`

```
<?php
   // Connects to your Database
   mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "Hxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("core_config") or die(mysql_error());

   $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vrf group by vrf") or die(mysql_error());

   echo "<table border cellpadding=3>";

      while ( $info = mysql_fetch_array ( $data )) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo " <th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['Switch'] . "</td> ";
         echo " <th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['vlan'] . "</td> ";
         echo " <th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['ip_address'] . "</td> ";
         echo "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['vrf'] . " </td></tr>";
      }

   echo "</table>";
?>
```

Try with this code. it should be work. (not tested)

```
<?php
   // Connects to your Database
   mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "Hxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("core_config") or die(mysql_error());

   $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vrf group by vrf") or die(mysql_error());

    // Print table header
   echo "<table border cellpadding=3>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name:</th>
                    <th>Name:</th>
                    <th>Name:</th>
                    <th>Pet:</th>
                </tr>";

   while ( $info = mysql_fetch_array ( $data )) {
      echo "<tr>
                <td>".$info['Switch']."</td> 
                <td>".$info['vlan']."</td> 
                <td>".$info['ip_address']."</td> 
                <td>".$info['vrf'] . "</td>
            </tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't get executed at all. Make sure you have named your script correctly (usually it should end in .PHP) and you have configured the server correctly to run PHP scripts.

This is a server configuration or file naming issue, not a PHP programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

So your code is not being parsed by the PHP interpreter. I presume that printing a result-set is not the only thing that doesn't work.

> For some reason when I execute the html in a browser I dont get the desired result.

You need to do all these things:

- Install and configure a web server
- Install and configure the PHP interpreter
- Save your files with `.php` extension
- Make sure you load your files through the web server, e.g. by typing `http://...`-something in your browser, rather than using File / Open.

Ensure you are able to accomplish a simple `echo` statement before attempting more complicated stuff.